# Can we add labels to a pull request while creation using rest API?

Tags: github-api

I am trying to create a pull request along with labels included during creation. I am aware this can be done in GitHub UI, but is it possible to do the same using REST API programatically?

The API documentation for creating a pull request doesn't mention specifying labels:
https://docs.github.com/en/rest/reference/pulls#create-a-pull-request

I used the following command to create a PR:

```
execute_command_with_output(
    'curl --silent -X POST -H "Authorization: token {}" -H "Accept: application/vnd.github.v3+json" '
    '{}/repos/{}/pulls -d \'{{"head":"{}","base":"{}","title":"{} Cherry-Pick from PR {}","labels":"bug"}}\''.format(
        token, url, repository, t_branch, b_branch, ticket, pr
    ),
```

Comment: What effect did `"labels":"bug"` have?

Answer (score 14):

It's not possible to do it **at the Pull Request creation** using the Github API (yet).

However, you can call **another Github service from the API** to add labels to the Pull Request after its creation. The related service is the [Add Label To An Issue](https://docs.github.com/en/rest/reference/issues#add-labels-to-an-issue).

**You read it right**: `TO AN ISSUE`!

Actually, `issue_number` and `pr_number` use the **SAME sequence** on a Github user repository and seem to refer to the same object when consumed by the Github API [for all those labels services](https://docs.github.com/en/rest/reference/issues#labels).

(*I wasn't aware of this fact before looking for the answer to this question!*)

##### Here is the cURL you'll need to use (example adding the `enhancement` label)

```
curl --location --request POST 'https://api.github.com/repos/{repo_owner}/{repo_name}/issues/{pr_number}/labels' \
--header 'Accept: application/vnd.github.v3+json' \
--header 'Authorization: Bearer {GITHUB_PAT}' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
--data-raw '{
    "labels": ["enhancement"]
}'
```

The `labels` field represents the names of the labels to add to the issue / PR.

*Note 1: You can also pass an empty array to remove all labels.*

*Note 2: You can also pass a single label as a string or an array of labels directly, but GitHub recommends passing an object with the labels key.*

##### References

I observed this behaviour on the official [Labeler action](https://github.com/actions/labeler) on the Github Marketplace on the [addLabels method implementation](https://github.com/actions/labeler/blob/11f610598291b2bac750f869d55def4239362c7f/dist/index.js#L219) for PR (which is the same than for ISSUES).

Then, I confirm it though [this post on the Github Community](https://github.community/t/create-pull-request-and-add-labels-in-a-single-request/116146) asking the same question as yours.