# Github Workflow - Remove label at the end?

Tags: github, github-actions

I have [a workflow](https://github.com/Leonardo-Ferreira/Casbin.NET/blob/fixSonarForForkPR/.github/workflows/sonar.yml) that is triggered when the pull request is labeled (via `pull_request_target`).

I would to automatically remove the label that triggered the analysis as the last step of that workflow.

How can I do that?

Comment: what have you tried so far and how has that not worked?

Comment: couldn't find anything remotely like what I need... there's a lot of examples on how to add labels... if you take a look at the workflow linked, the last step (commented now) was my latest stab a the problem...

Comment: since you attempted to solve it in a specific way, perhaps you could share how that didn't work? just linking to your code and asking people to solve the problem for you is not going to be beneficial for future visitors, so it would be good if you could demonstrate what you have tried, the problems you faced and the specific questions you have around that.

Comment: Every pull request is an issue (but not every issue is a pull request). Therefore, you could use the Github Api to remove a (specific) label from an issue (or an action doing the same thing) as the last step of your workflow, using the PR number. Related API on Github: https://docs.github.com/en/rest/reference/issues#remove-a-label-from-an-issue

Answer (score 3):

GuiFalourd does indeed have the correct answer, but I did have to improve on it a bit.

If you want to use the workflow on a private repo, you do need to add an authorization token. Here's an example that uses GitHub context to populate everything besides the label name you want to delete:

```
curl --silent --fail-with-body \
  -X DELETE \
  -H 'Accept: application/vnd.github.v3+json' \
  -H 'Authorization: token ${{ github.token }}' \
  'https://api.github.com/repos/${{ github.repository }}/issues/${{ github.event.number }}/labels/YOUR-LABEL'
```

Also if your label has spaces, use `%20` for the whitespace.

Answer (score 2):

On Github: **every pull request is an issue** (but not every issue is a pull request).

*[You can find more informations about this on this stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68459601/can-we-add-labels-to-a-pull-request-while-creation-using-rest-api/68461800#68461800).*

Therefore, you could use the **Github API** to remove a (specific) label from an issue (or an action doing the same thing) as the last step of your workflow, using the PR number.

*[Here is the API on Github to remove label from issue (Official Documentation)](https://docs.github.com/en/rest/reference/issues#remove-a-label-from-an-issue)*

If you want to call it directly from the shell in your workflow with curl, it will looks like this:

```
curl \
  -X DELETE \
  -H "Accept: application/vnd.github.v3+json" \
  https://api.github.com/repos/<owner>/<repo>/issues/<pr_number>/labels/<label_name>
```